# Random Username Generator Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I'm currently using Visual Studio to build my website and I'm getting stuck on my username generator. I need it because I don't want any inappropriate words and this is a children's website so I don't want to use real information. I thought about using an array of strings and then adding them together but for some reason, I can't get it to work -__- any help would be appreciated. I'm in coding boot camp and my teacher said this would be a useful place for information. Thanks.

So far, this is what I have:

```
var a = ["Small", "Blue", "Ugly"];
var b = ["Bear", "Dog", "Banana"];

var rA = Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length);
var rB = Math.floor(Math.random()*b.length);
var name = a[rA] + b[rB];
alert(name);
```

Now my issue is I'm trying to write a function that will generate a new name with every click. I know I need function myFunction() and an onclick= event. Hopefully this is not a vague as before.

Comment: So is the question how to generate a random string at all, or how to exclude certain inappropriate words that might come up randomly? Presumably you'd also need to exclude any user names that have already been taken...

Comment: I'm just worrying about how to generate the random string for now. I'll focus on the excluding certain words later @nnnnnn...if you have any ideas, please do share.

Comment: Well, an array of permitted characters, then [generate a random number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Using_Math.random()) between 0 and the end of the array to select one such character. Do in a loop to build up a string of the desired length.

Comment: also, I don't want to generate random chars, I want 2 full words to be added together. a adj and noun...(so if the array had ["Small","Blue","Ugly"]; and another had ["Bear","Dog","Banana"]; you could possibly get "BlueBanana" or "UglyBear").

Comment: Well that'll work with something like what I just suggested.

Comment: I'm going to try it in JSFiddle now..Thanks for the quick response :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this, (looking at comments)

```
var a = ["Small", "Blue", "Ugly"];
var b = ["Bear", "Dog", "Banana"];

var rA = Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length);
var rB = Math.floor(Math.random()*b.length);
var name = a[rA] + b[rB];
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! For some reason, I was forgetting how to use Math.radom. Guess I need to study more! :)